# How stop Azure Pipeline Self-Hosted agent to delete sources

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have an Azure Pipeline Self-Hosted agent (Windows) I configured on one of my laptops, so everything is persistent; the pipeline that uses that, clones the repository, then runs a CMake configure which further downloads several submodules through `git submodule update --init`.

Although I think I configured the pipeline in any way I could to only clean outputs, so binaries, not sources, on each new run the submodules gets downloaded again.
I know that it starts with an empty repostory because in the checkout step log I see:

```
git init "C:\agent\_work\3\s"
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/agent/_work/3/s/.git/
```

I've checked here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#job and set the workspace attribute clean to `clean: outputs`.
Checked here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#checkout and set the checkout attribute clean to `clean: false`.
I've also controlled that the configuration of the pipeline on the website had not the clean attribute active.

I seem to recall somewhere around 6 months ago or more (when you had `clean: binaries` instead), that this was working correctly.

Here is a very simplified version of what the pipeline looks like:

```
jobs:
  - job: AJob
    displayName: "A job"

    pool: "Self Hosted"

    workspace:
      clean: outputs

    steps:
    - powershell: |
        git config --global core.autocrlf false
        git config --global core.symlinks true

    - checkout: self
      clean: false

    - powershell: |
        git submodule update --init <path to submodule>
```

EDIT:
To add even more info, enabling the debug variable for the run I see this in the log when it initializes the Job:

```
##[debug]Delete existing build directory: 'C:\agent\_work\3' <---- why :\
##[debug]Deleting build directory: 'C:\agent\_work\3'
##[debug]Creating build directory: 'C:\agent\_work\3'
##[debug]Delete existing artifacts directory: 'C:\agent\_work\3\a'
##[debug]Creating artifacts directory: 'C:\agent\_work\3\a'
##[debug]Delete existing test results directory: 'C:\agent\_work\3\TestResults'
##[debug]Creating test results directory: 'C:\agent\_work\3\TestResults'
##[debug]Creating binaries directory: 'C:\agent\_work\3\b'
##[debug]Creating source directory: 'C:\agent\_work\3\s'
```

Is anyone else experiencing this and knows how to resolve?

Comment: If you want help with a pipeline, you should post the YAML.

Comment: @DanielMann I've added a very simplified version of YAML I tested which reproduces the same issue.
What I see is that the submodule gets cloned each new run when running the `git submodule` command, while if I would do that locally, nothing would happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Discovered that it was the variable `build.clean: all` set through the UI, from another portion I didn't look at.
Specifically this was in the Variables tab when editing the pipeline.
Simpler than I thought.

Answer (score 0):

Submodule init is natively supported and does not require inline scripts. Refer to the [YAML schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#checkout).

```
steps:
- checkout: self | none | repository name # self represents the repo where the initial Pipelines YAML file was found
  clean: boolean  # if true, run `execute git clean -ffdx && git reset --hard HEAD` before fetching
  fetchDepth: number  # the depth of commits to ask Git to fetch; defaults to no limit
  lfs: boolean  # whether to download Git-LFS files; defaults to false
  submodules: true | recursive  # set to 'true' for a single level of submodules or 'recursive' to get submodules of submodules; defaults to not checking out submodules
  path: string  # path to check out source code, relative to the agent's build directory (e.g. \_work\1); defaults to a directory called `s`
  persistCredentials: boolean  # if 'true', leave the OAuth token in the Git config after the initial fetch; defaults to false
```

You want to set `submodules` to either `true` or `recursive` and remove your in-line script.

Comment: Thanks for this answer but, the YAML I've shown is a simplified version, which means that it doesn't use CMake to clone submodules, though the CMake script does launch `git submodule update --init <submodule>`.
The difference is that it doesn't do that on ALL submodules, because I don't want that; CMake is there to select which submodules have to be cloned.

Answer (score -1):

Delete the ..\agent\work folder from the agent machine and it will stop all the running/deleted/stuck jobs.

Comment: The request was how to stop the agent from deleting sources.